# Retrieve send emails from email server

Tags: smtp, pop3

Is there a way to 'ask' email server to send copy of currently stored outgoing (sent) emails back to client ?
Is there some text based pop3 client that would allow preparing siutable request for this ?
Unfortuantely I don't have any specific details about email server, nor do I look for vounrability.

Comment: Is there a reason to use pop3? imap client can retrieve Sent folder e.g., as '[Gmail]/Sent Mail'

Comment: No there isn't, maybe for compatibility sake, I'll learn how imap works if it has this capability.

Comment: Here's a [code example that shows how to get email in a given time period](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22159037/4279). It prints sent mail if you replace `.select('INBOX')` with `.select('"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"')`. You could use `from pprint import pprint; pprint(mail.list()[1])`, to see what else you could `select`.